# Show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(-(1-p)\cdot x+\ln\left(p\cdot e^{x(1-p)}+(1-p)\cdot e^{-xp}\right)\right)=\ln(p)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let be $0<p<1$ and $f:]0,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x):=-(1-p)\cdot x+\ln\left(p\cdot e^{x(1-p)}+(1-p)\cdot e^{-xp}\right)$.
>
> Then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(-(1-p)\cdot x+\ln\left(p\cdot e^{x(1-p)}+(1-p)\cdot e^{-xp}\right)\right)=\ln(p)$.

---

This is a statement from our lecture but I fail to show it. After some manipulations I get

\begin{align*}
&-(1-p)\cdot x+\ln\left(p\cdot e^{x(1-p)}+(1-p)\cdot e^{-xp}\right)\\
&=-(1-p)\cdot x+ \ln\left(e^{-xp}\left(pe^{x}+1-p\right)\right)\\
&=-(1-p)\cdot x -xp+\ln\left(pe^{x}+1-p\right)\\
&=\ln\left(pe^{x}+1-p\right)-x=\dots?
\end{align*}

Intuitively, it makes sense that large $x$ will make the summand $1-p$ inside the logarithm irrelevant, so that $\ln\left(pe^{x}+1-p\right)\approx \ln\left(pe^{x}\right)=\ln(p)+x$.

But how do I show this rigorously? Is there some tricky manipulation??

Comment: At $p\in(0;1)$, if $x\to \infty\,\, (1-p)e^{-xp}\to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$f_p(x) = -(1-p)x+\ln\left(pe^{x(1-p)}+(1-p)e^{-xp}\right) = -(1-p)x+\ln\left(e^{x(1-p)}\left(p+(1-p)e^{-x}\right)\right) = -(1-p)x+\ln\left(e^{x(1-p)}\right)+\ln\left(p+(1-p)e^{-x}\right)=\ln\left(p+(1-p)e^{-x}\right).$$

Now clearly, using the continuity of $\ln$ and the fact that $e^{-x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, this yields that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f_p(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(p+(1-p)e^{-x}\right)=\ln(p)$$

as desired.

Comment: there is a little typo: the $e^x$ of the first summand in the first line is wrong.

Comment: @Philipp fixed the typo, the solution works regardless